# TSQL - Calculate values for plants and years over months

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, calculated-columns

I have the following Excel calculation that I want to replicate to a T-SQL statement:
[image: example]

This Excel is imported to a SQL table (SQL Server 2012) in the same format with two additional columns for plant and year.

Below is my SQL view that I use for reporting. As you can see the months became rows and the value-columns rows:

```
+---------+------+-------+------+--------+
|  Plant  | Year | Month |  A   |   B    |
+---------+------+-------+------+--------+
| Plant X | 2019 |     1 |  526 | 16     |
| Plant X | 2019 |     2 |  786 | 54     |
| Plant X | 2019 |     3 | 1800 | 85     |
| Plant X | 2019 |     4 | 9780 | 15     |
| Plant X | 2019 |     5 | 9780 | (null) |
| Plant Y | 2019 |     1 | 4080 | 128    |
| Plant Y | 2019 |     2 | 1387 | 179    |
+---------+------+-------+------+--------+
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c1397b/1) for above sql view.

```
CREATE TABLE Test
    ([Plant] varchar(13), [Year] int, [Month] int, [A] decimal(18,2), [B] decimal(18,2))
;

INSERT INTO Test
    ([Plant], [Year], Month, A, B)
VALUES
    ('Plant X', 2019,1,526 ,16 ),
    ('Plant X', 2019,2,786 ,54),
    ('Plant X', 2019,3, 1800,85),
    ('Plant X', 2019,4, 9780,15),
    ('Plant X', 2019,5, 9780,NULL),
    ('Plant Y', 2019,1,4080 ,128 ),
    ('Plant Y', 2019,2,1387 ,179)
;
```

Is it possible to do the calculation in my SQL view as depicted in above Excel image? If yes, can you show an example?

Since I also have the data in an SQL table just like the Excel structure (with months as columns) would that make more sense to do the calculation in that format?

Thank you.

Comment: There are loads of examples on how to Pivot data on Stack Overflow (personally I recommend the Cross Tab method). What of those did you try, and why didn't they work?

Comment: The Calculated row is an aggregation row and should be calculated in the display application, not in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a fast way and with your sample table, it could be like this:

```
select t.*
    , Calculated = (
        select cast(round(sum(B) * 1000000 / sum(A), 0) as int)
        from Test
        where Plant = t.Plant
            and [Year] = t.[Year]
            and [Month] <= t.[Month]
        having sum(A) <> 0
        )
from Test t
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of having to unpivot some columns and pivot on another one. To unpivot, I use a `CROSS APPLY` and a `table values constructor` which is very versatile (unlike the unpivot operator). I also use the cross tabs method to pivot data.

```
SELECT  Plant, [Year], colName,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 1 THEN colValue END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 2 THEN colValue END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 3 THEN colValue END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 4 THEN colValue END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 5 THEN colValue END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 6 THEN colValue END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 7 THEN colValue END)
FROM Test
CROSS APPLY( VALUES( 'A', A),( 'B', B)) AS x(colName, colValue)
GROUP BY Plant, [Year], colName
ORDER BY Plant, [Year], colName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by using PIVOT and UNPIVOT in TSQL.

```
SELECT [Plant]
  ,[Year]
  ,[newColumn]
  ,SUM([1]) [1]
  ,SUM([2]) [2]
  ,SUM([3]) [3]
  ,SUM([4]) [4]
  ,SUM([5]) [5]
FROM [Test]
UNPIVOT(Orders FOR newColumn IN (
          A
         ,B
        )) AS unpvt
PIVOT(SUM([Orders]) FOR [Month] IN (
         [1]
        ,[2]
        ,[3]
        ,[4]
        ,[5]
        )) AS PivotTable
GROUP BY [Plant]
  ,[Year]
  ,[newColumn]
```